# HTML Form submit to spreadsheet, redirect and automatic email notification doesn't work simultaneous on iOs

Tags: php, html, ios, forms, google-sheets

First I'm sorry, my english isn't good.
I created a form have 3 features:
+Sending data to spreadsheet
+Automatic email notification for me when someone submit the form
+Redirect to thanksYou.html page (set GOAL for Google Analytics)

The problem is everything works fine in Android, Windows, Mac but it doesn't work in iOs (iphone and Ipad).

I make a form send data to spreadsheet by follow these steps:
http://railsrescue.com/blog/2015-05-28-step-by-step-setup-to-send-form-data-to-google-sheets/

To make a email notification, I insert these code:

```
requestEmail = $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.mysite.vn/form/sent.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });
```

Inside sent.php file:

```
<?php
 $msg = 'Full name: ' .$_POST['ho_va_ten'] ."\n"
           .'Phone number: ' .$_POST['phone'] ."\n"
           .'Email: ' .$_POST['e-mail'];    
mail('mymail@gmail.com' , 'Header Mail', $msg);
 ?>
```

In the end of codes I insert this code to redirect (The form is inside a iframe)

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

So where am I wrong?
Thank you very much for the prompt reply!